# Draw a Pattern to a rectangle in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

As the title says, I’m trying to get a pattern drawn to a rectangle. I’ve created a rectangle constructor function to draw multiple rectangles and 
then stored them in an array in order to loop through and call the `createRect()` function.

The problem is, the canvas ends up completely black.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("slideshow");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = [];
var img_height = 380;
var img_length = 475.75;









function picture(){


this.img_height = img_height;
this.img_length = img_length;
this.X = 0;


this.getX = function(num) {

    switch(num){

    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        this.X = this.img_length;
        break;
    case 3:
        this.X = this.img_length * 2;
        break;
    case 4: 
        this.X = this.img_length * 3;
        break;
    case 5:
        this.X = -this.img_length;
        break;  
    };




};

this.createRect = function(num){

    this.obj = document.getElementById('p' + num);
    this.pattern = ctx.createPattern(this.obj, 'no-repeat');
    ctx.fillStyle = this.pattern;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillRect(this.X, 0, this.img_length,this.img_height);
    ctx.fill();





    }



};
```

Theser are the loops to create each object and display them.

```
//Create objects
for(let i = 0;i<=5;i++)
    {
        img[i-1] = new picture();
    }

//get x coords and display
for(let i = 0;i<5;i++)
    {
        img[i].getX(i+1);
        img[i].createRect(i+1);
    }
```

Comment: img[i - 1] ... you cannot reference element of array with negative index. (with i=0~5)

Comment: So start debugging your code methodically. If you _don't_ draw any rectangles, does it look as expected? Then, if you draw _one_ rectangle, does that look as expected? (And remember to look at the developer console. Are there any errors?) If not, "adding more rectangles" is not part of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've invented a class _Rect tor the method `createRect()` you have. This example won't work on SO but you can see a working example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/da36407d6180f8d29de6ee1f2ba96a41?editors=0011)

Please make sure you are using an image from the same domain.

```js
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

class _Rect{
  constructor(o){
    this.X = o.x;
    this.y = o.y;
    this.img_length = o.w;
    this.img_height = o.h
  }

  createRect() {
  this.object = document.getElementById('p1');
  this.pattern = ctx.createPattern(this.object, 'no-repeat');
  ctx.fillStyle = this.pattern;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillRect(this.X, 0, this.img_length, this.img_height);
  ctx.strokeRect(this.X, 0, this.img_length, this.img_height);
};
}
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<img id="p1" src="pin.png" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
I´ve tried your idea, but the rectangle where i try to draw the patter, is still black.

Comment: Sometimes when i reload the page, the image shows for a second.Weird.
Is it because of my method? Should i create a class?

Comment: I don't know. I thought this was part of a class. Please share a simplified version of your code: a working example.

Comment: I´ve updated the post with my complete code.
Html is not so important i guess. I´ve just added 5 img tags.

Comment: I found out that if i press F5 the images dont get loaded. When i re-enter the link in the url-bar, the images get displayed but not in the size i want